# JMeter using numeric variable in JSON request body

Tags: java, jmeter

When making a request with a JSON body, the string variables are replaced as expected but not the numeric ones. For the example below:

```
{
  "name": "${userName}"
  "age": ${userAge}
}
```

This is what reaches the server:

```
{
  "name": "My Name"
  "age": ${userAge}
}
```

What do I need to do in order to get the variable replaced with the number as I'm expecting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to do anything special, just make sure that your `${userAge}` variable exists and has its respective value, you can do it using [Debug Sampler and View Results Tree listener combination](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/debug-jmeter).

You also need to add a comma after `name` attribute otherwise your [JSON will not be valid](https://jsonlint.com/).

```
{
  "name": "${userName}",
  "age": ${userAge}
}
```

[image]